# Django forms not returning result or errors

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to use a Django form for a login page, but the form is returning False whenever I call form.is_valid(). I tried to print the errors in the console and in the HTML file but there's nothing displaying. I tried to get data from the form with form["email"].value() and it's returning None, even when I input data into the email field.

Here's views.py:

```
def postlogin(request):
    form = BootstrapAuthenticationForm(request.POST)

    # This prints out None into the console
    print(form["email"].value())

    if form.is_valid():
        # This code never runs! Even when there are no errors in the form fields!
        return render(request, "app/home.html")

    # If form is invalid, return to login page
    # This always runs, meaning form.is_valid() keeps being false!
    return render(request,"app/login.html", {"form":form})
```

Here's my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class BootstrapAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    """Authentication form which uses boostrap CSS."""
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=254,label=('Email'),
                               widget=forms.TextInput({
                                   'class': 'form-control',
                                   'placeholder': 'Email'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label=("Password"),
                               widget=forms.PasswordInput({
                                   'class': 'form-control',
                                   'placeholder':'Password'}))
```

Here's my login.html:

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h2>{{ title }}</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section id="loginForm">
            <form action="/postlogin/" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                <hr />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_username" class="col-md-2 control-label">{{form.email.label}}</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        {{ form.email }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_password" class="col-md-2 control-label">{{form.password.label}}</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        {{ form.password }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_password" class="col-md-2 control-label">{{form.test.label}}</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Nothing below shows even when form.is_valid() is false -->
                {% if form.errors %}
                <p class="validation-summary-errors">Please enter a correct user name and password.</p>
                {% endif %}
                {% if form.non_field_errors %}
                <p class="validation-summary-errors">Please enter a correct user name and password.</p>
                {% endif %}
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <section id="socialLoginForm"></section>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Again, none of this shows in the HTML file even when form.is_valid() is False -->
{% for error_field, error_message in form.errors.items %}
{{ error_field|striptags }}: {{ error_message|striptags }}
{% endfor %}


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: try  ----->   print form.cleaned_data['email']  
also process post data explicitly by mentioning --->  if request.method == 'POST':

Comment: I can't even get to print form.cleaned_data['email'] because form.is_valid() runs and returns False. I'll try request.method == 'POST' though. Although I think the real issue is that I do ```print (form["email"].value())``` and it prints None

Comment: please attach the view from which you are passing the form and rendering the login.html page ... Try printing ---->  print(form)   print(form.errors) right after you set -----> form = BootstrapAuthenticationForm(request.POST)

Answer (score 0):

```
if form.is_valid():
  # after validating form you can print field value using (cleaned_data) method
  print(form.cleaned_data['email'])
  return render(request, "app/home.html")
```